# Removing external js file dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to remove the js file on mouseclick. I am referring to www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss2.shtml  for removing
But its not working for me
This is my corresponding code

HTML part:

```
<div id="dropdownlist" style="position:absolute;z-index:102;">
                  <a href="#" onclick="DisplayDropdownSelectedPage('blog')">BLOG</a><br/><a href="#" onclick="DisplayDropdownSelectedPage('careers')">CAREERS</a><br/><a href="#" onclick="DisplayDropdownSelectedPage('whistleblower')">WHISTLE BLOWSER</a><br/><a href="#" onclick="DisplayDropdownSelectedPage('disclaimer')">DISCLAIMER</a><br/><a href="#" onclick="DisplayDropdownSelectedPage('sitemap')">SITEMAP</a><br/><a href="#" onclick="DisplayDropdownSelectedPage('feedback')">FEEDBACK</a><br/>
                </div>
```

JS part:

```
function removejscssfile(filename, filetype){
 var targetelement=(filetype=="js")? "script" : (filetype=="css")? "link" : "none" //determine element type to create nodelist from
 var targetattr=(filetype=="js")? "src" : (filetype=="css")? "href" : "none" //determine corresponding attribute to test for
 var allsuspects=document.getElementsByTagName(targetelement)
 for (var i=allsuspects.length; i>=0; i--){ //search backwards within nodelist for matching elements to remove
  if (allsuspects[i] && allsuspects[i].getAttribute(targetattr)!=null && allsuspects[i].getAttribute(targetattr).indexOf(filename)!=-1)
   allsuspects[i].parentNode.removeChild(allsuspects[i]) //remove element by calling parentNode.removeChild()
 }
}

function DisplayDropdownSelectedPage(dropdownname)
{
    var width=$(window).width();
    var height=$(window).height();
    var top=document.getElementById("globelHead").offsetHeight;
    var animateheight=(height-top);
    var animatewidth=(width/2);
    var shiftright=(-(animatewidth)+"px");
    if(dropdownname=="blog")
    {
        removejscssfile("myscript.js", "js")
        $("#Blog").css({"width":animatewidth+"px","height":animateheight,"right":shiftright,"top":top});
        $("#Blog").show().animate({right:'0%'},1200);
        $("#Careers").hide();
        $("#WhistleBlower").hide();
        $("#Disclaimer").hide();
        $("#SiteMap").hide();
        $("#Feedback").hide();

    }
    else if(dropdownname=="careers")
    {
        removejscssfile("myscript.js", "js")
        $("#Blog").hide();
        $("#Careers").css({"width":animatewidth+"px","height":animateheight,"right":shiftright,"top":top});
        $("#Careers").show().animate({right:'0%'},1200);
        $("#WhistleBlower").hide();
        $("#Disclaimer").hide();
        $("#SiteMap").hide();
        $("#Feedback").hide();
    }
    else if(dropdownname=="whistleblower")
    {
        removejscssfile("myscript.js", "js")
        $("#Blog").hide();
        $("#Careers").hide();
        $("#WhistleBlower").css({"width":animatewidth+"px","height":animateheight,"right":shiftright,"top":top});
        $("#WhistleBlower").show().animate({right:'0%'},1200);
        $("#Disclaimer").hide();
        $("#SiteMap").hide();
        $("#Feedback").hide();
    }
    else if(dropdownname=="disclaimer")
    {   
        removejscssfile("myscript.js", "js")
        $("#Blog").hide();
        $("#Careers").hide();
        $("#WhistleBlower").hide();
        $("#Disclaimer").css({"width":animatewidth+"px","height":animateheight,"right":shiftright,"top":top});
        $("#Disclaimer").show().animate({right:'0%'},1200);
        $("#SiteMap").hide();
        $("#Feedback").hide();

    }
    else if(dropdownname=="sitemap")
    {

        $("#Blog").hide();
        $("#Careers").hide();
        $("#WhistleBlower").hide();
        $("#Disclaimer").hide();
        $("#SiteMap").css({"width":animatewidth+"px","height":animateheight,"right":shiftright,"top":top});
        $("#SiteMap").show().animate({right:'0%'},1200);
        $("#Feedback").hide();

    }
    else if(dropdownname=="feedback")
    {
        $("#Blog").hide();
        $("#Careers").hide();
        $("#WhistleBlower").hide();
        $("#Disclaimer").hide();
        $("#SiteMap").hide();
        $("#Feedback").css({"width":animatewidth+"px","height":animateheight,"right":shiftright,"top":top});
        $("#Feedback").show().animate({right:'0%'},1200);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Do not quite understand your problem, but if you need to delete a file from DOM document then add to script tag attribute id and remove.

```
<script id="mustBeRemoved">....
$("#mustBeRemoved").remove();
```

Comment: dont u think it cause confusion When u give ID to script ,like "Well I give id to divs ,spans etc ,So i think i m removing the div from DOM".

Comment: In HTML5 allowed attribute tag to ALL DOM elements, so I do not see a problem in this

Comment: I NEVER said there is problem,i said It will cause LOT of Confusion whether its div ,span, paragraph, a href or something else.

Comment: @SergeevD i dont want to delete a file i just want to disable the file for sometime(on mouseclick or clicking on a div) and again to enable it after clicking on another div.However the above solution is not working for me

Comment: And then I did not understand your problem. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Try this i tested this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#cats').click(function(){  


        $('head script[src*="jquery-ui.js"]').remove();

    });
});
```

Try it in HTML file,js file gets removed when clicked on image

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#cats').click(function(){  


        $('head script[src*="jquery-ui.js"]').remove();

    });
});
</script>
<title>Birman Cats</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>  Black Cat Superstitions</h1>
<div id="black">
<h2>  Folk Lore</h2>
<div id="cats">
<p><img src="http://s.w.org/style/images/wp-header-logo.png?1"/></p></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its not working still,i am putting this part in inside my html file, am i correct .e.g the js file i want to disable is pa.js,so should i disable it from inside my html or from another external js ,am a new comer i dont have any idea on how js loads

Comment: provide URL of ur site , i dont understand your error

Comment: It must work ,check updated answer and execute is as it is in HTML file.Just see header at start and what happen when u click on image.